# fadeIn effect for a click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not able to get the `fadeIn` effect to work on the click event for the images.

I want them to fade In when clicked... `fadeOut` and `fadeToggle` work, but `fadeIn` won't. I have searched and tried all things found with no success.

I am sure this something super simple that I am overlooking but simply cannot figure this out!

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // preload images
    $("#image_list a").each(function() {
        var swappedImage = new Image();
        swappedImage.src = $(this).attr("href");
    });
    // set up event handlers for links    
    $("#image_list a").click(function(evt) {
        var imageURL = $(this).attr("href");
        $("#image").attr("src", imageURL).fadeIn(1000);

        var caption = $(this).attr("title");
        $("#caption").text(caption);

        // cancel the default action of the link
        evt.preventDefault();
    }); // end click
    // move focus to first thumbnail
    $("li:first-child a").focus();
}); // end ready
```

Comment: Where are you trying to use `fadeIn`? I don't see it in your code

Comment: $('#image').attr("src", imageURL).fadeIn(1000);  sorry I have never posted here before...

Comment: you try to fade in the picture after you set the source, right?

Comment: I believe so... I fixed the code to show where I am doing the fadeIn.

Comment: Can you also show your html?

Comment: I tried, but it won't let me.  how do I show the HTML? I would gladly do it for you! :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to put thoses preloaded images into the target element first and hide it. Then you can fadein.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // preload images
  $("#image_list a").each(function() {
    var swappedImage = new Image();
    swappedImage.src = $(this).attr("href");
    $(this).append(swappedImage);
    $(swappedImage).hide();
  });
  // set up event handlers for links    
  $("#image_list a").click(function(evt) {

    // cancel the default action of the link
    evt.preventDefault();
    $("img").fadeIn(5000);

    var caption = $(this).attr("title");
    $("#caption").text(caption);
  }); // end click
  // move focus to first thumbnail
  $("li:first-child a").focus();
}); // end ready
```

Comment: this just made a mess of the whole page.  AHH!  I wish I could get the HTML up there for you to see.  Thank you!

Comment: The idea is that you should worry about these 2 lines: `$(this).append(swappedImage);
    $(swappedImage).hide();`